# Content in Listview is invisible

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Android and I am currently developing an app that contains a listview with simple text. When the user clicks the text in the listview  a sharing intent is triggered. I have used a custom adapter to set a different typeface to the text in my listview. The problem is when I run the app the listview is being seen but the content is invisible. But When I tap on the listview the sharing intent is triggered as it should be. I don't know what is causing it. I searched in Stack Overflow and google and tried some steps but it didn't work out for me. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Code:

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.proda.technologies.app.testapp"
android:background="@drawable/inspirationalbg">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/back_Button"
    android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/back_Button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/instView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context,R.layout.list_item,values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   View rview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    TextView txt = (TextView)rview.findViewById(R.id.instView);
    AssetManager mgr = context.getAssets();
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr,"fonts/RalewayRegular.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(tf);
    return rview;
}


}
```

**Main.java**

```
String[] phone = {"Nexus","Htc","Samsung","Oppo","Apple"};
Listview inslist;
inslist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Main.this,phone);
inslist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am not getting any errors. I can see the listview with the lines seperating each content. But the actual content(text) is invisible. Please help me

Comment: first of all, open the dev settings on your device and enable 'Show layout bounds' reopen your app and take a look at the list items layout, are the components actually on screen.

Comment: You're using #fff for your text, if your background on the listview is white, you won't see it

Comment: @Pztar The text color is not the problem. I checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ListViewItem contain a TextView but its value was not init.
Try to set value for textView in xml file or in java code.
Try one of below ways:

**1. By XML file: list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/instView"
    android:text="This is text sample"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**2. by Java code: CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;


public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context,R.layout.list_item,values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   View rview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
    TextView txt = (TextView)rview.findViewById(R.id.instView);
    txt.setText(values[position]);
    AssetManager mgr = context.getAssets();
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr,"fonts/RalewayRegular.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(tf);
    return rview;
}


}
```

Comment: I tried both the methods but the listview is displaying only the "This is text sample". It is not displaying the contents of the String[] phone.

Comment: check my edit for CustomAdapter again, I had change how to setText for TextView as you want

Comment: remember that in getCount() you should return size of values

Comment: I used that txt.setText(values[position]) and it worked Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see anywhere that you added text inside TextView.

Can you put the data to show in TextView view inside getView() method like :

```
txt.setText(values.get(position));
```

Comment: @Ranjith Pati  the values.get(position) is not available? Is there any other ways to set the text in values to txt?